# I want to display date in the format of dd-mm-yyyy and by checking whether its variable value is null or true

Tags: angularjs, html, data-binding

in angularjs data binding to display the date from a variable we use `{{userDate | date:'dd:MM:yyyy'}}` and of we want to display something by checking the variable's value we use `{{userDate? userDate: 'Not Available'}}` which means if userDate is there we display its value or else we display not available
what i want is to check userData value is there or not if it is there i want to display it in date format else display not available

Check the code below for example

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<input type="date" ng-model="userDate">
<div style="border: 1px solid blue">
    <p>Date: {{userDate? userDate:'Date not entered' }}</p>  
    <p>This is default stored date</p>
    </div>
    <div style="border: 1px solid blue">
    <p>Date: {{userDate | date:'dd:mm:yyyy'}}</p>
    <p>This is formatted date</p>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.userDate = '';
    
});
</script>

<p>I want the formatted date when th userDate variable has some date if not display not available.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what i want is to check userData value is there or not if it is there i want to display it in date format else display not available

If I understand you right you can write as:

```
<p>Date: {{userDate? (userDate | date:'dd:mm:yyyy'):'Date not entered' }}</p>
```

---

<kbd>[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9sprrp3r/)</kbd>